# Set a field in all the children of an item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I have an Item in sitecore lets say "`AddressItem`" that has some children. I want to edit a Field "IsMain" in all the child items.

I am using `Foreach` loop. Is there some better way to achieve this.

```
foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item child in AddressItem.Children)
{
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        child.Editing.BeginEdit();
        child.Fields["IsMain"].Value = "0";
        child.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of SecurityDisabler you can also use the UserSwitcher, What is your issue?, this is not very fast?. and probably you want to do this only in the master db? For bulk operations you can also use Sitecore Rocks.

Comment: Yes I also think that its not fast that's why I posted my question here. I want to know the fast way to achieve the same result.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably faster to set the IsMain fields standard value to 0 then reset all items to that standard value. There is no function for that out of the box but the below code will do it.

This function is a little more robust then your requirement but its the code I have as is.

First you need a user with the correct permissions to replace: ElevatedUserAccount

Next get the list of items you would like to reset the values for then create a list of fields you wish to reset. In your case AddressItem.Children and IsMain.

Finally pass them into the below methods.

```
public void ResetFields(List<Item> items, List<string> fields)
{
    if (items.Any() && fields.Any())
    {
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
           ResetFieldsOnItem(item, fields);
        }
    }
}

public void ResetFieldsOnItem(Item item, List<string> fields)
{
    if (item != null && fields.Any())
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(ElevatedUserAccount, true))
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();

            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                item.Fields[field].Reset();
            }

            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```